# Convergence of $g(x)\cdot f(x)$

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Let $g(x)=\frac{1-e^{-x^2}}{x^2}$ for $x \neq 0$,$g(0)=1$ and $f(x)=e^{-(x-n)^2}$. You can assume that g(x) is continuous and bounded with maximum 1 in x=$0$. 
Show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}g(x)\cdot f(x)$ converges uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$.
I have been able to show that for $x \leq 0$: $$ \left|g(x)f(x)\right|\leq f(x) \leq e^{-n^2}$$ which converges. However, I am unable to use the M'test for x>0. Any ideas?

Comment: This has been asked [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1799319/prove-uniform-convergence-of-series).

Answer (score 0):

Look for maximum of $e^{2xn-x^2}$  then use that $g<1$ to get everything less then $h(n)e^{-n^2}$ for some $h$. I can tell you more if you want.

Comment: That would be great :) I'm not really sure i understand your answer. How did you come up with $e^{2xn-x^2}$?

Comment: Wouldnt the maximum of $e^(2*x*n-x^2)$ be $e^(n^2)$ thus making the value of the M test is 1????