# Prove uniform convergence of series

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

I'm given to functions, $f_{n}(x)=e^{-(x-n)^2}$ and $g(x)= \begin{cases} \frac{1-e^{-x^2}}{x^2} & x \neq 0 \\ 1 & x=0 \end{cases}$. I have to prove that $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} g(x) \cdot f_n(x) $$
converges uniformly.

I can assume that $g(x)$ is continuous and limited with maximum in $x=0$. I've tried Weierstrass M-test, but I can't get it to work out.

Comment: I don't know whether this would work, but you could try to find some bound on $\max(g(x)f_n(x))$, by something whose sum over $n$ converges.

Comment: This has been asked [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1799314/convergence-of-gx-cdot-fx).

Comment: @Arthur I can tell that $\max (g(x) f_n(x)) =1 \ \forall \ n$. But $\frac{1}{n}$ does not converge.

Comment: I've solved the problem if you can show that $ \frac{1 - e^{-x^2}}{x^2}e^{-(x-n)^2} < \frac{2}{n^2} $ for $0<x<n$

Answer (score 1):

I'll put it her as well:

Look for maximum of $e^{2xn-x^2}$  then use that $g<1$ to get everything less then $h(n)e^{-n^2}$ for some $h$. I can tell you more if you want.

We want a max for $e^{2xn-x^2}$, the derivative is $(2n-2x)e^{2xn-x^2}$ which is zero when $x=n$, now since for $x<n$ is positive and then is negative it is a local max (is actually a global max since the function goes to zero at $\pm\infty$). then in what I wrote above you get that $|gf|\leq n e^{-n^2}$ which is convergent.

Comment: I could use some more help. My brain is really fried after looking at this for several hours.

Comment: @RasmusTolker I edited the answer

Comment: This doesn't work, as $ \left| g(x) \cdot f_{n}(x) \right| \leq ne^{-n^2}$ is not true.